# Use XJC to generate sources from given XSD file with Mave

Tags: java, xml, maven, xsd, jaxb2

I have got two XSD-files. One is used to generate a whole bunch of Java source already. I'm about to build another XSD to create classes for another project. I want to use a class build by the first XSD as a "type" in my second XSD.
I tried to import the first XSD within my second one. 
But by this, the whole bunch of classes of the first XSD is build again.
I want to build just one new class defined in my new XSD using the correct reference (Class name and package name) for the used old class.

Sample:
oldXSD:

```
   <xs:element name="OldClass",....
   <xs:element name="OtherClass1",...
   <xs:element name="OtherClass2",...
   etc
```

newXSD:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://new.namespace.com"
    xmlns:empns="http://new.namespace.com" 
    xmlns:Q1="http://old.namespace.com">

    <xs:import namespace="http://old.namespace.com"
        schemaLocation="../oldXSD.xsd" />

    <xs:element name="bookingStatus" type="empns:BookingStatus"></xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="BookingStatus">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="userId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"
                maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="userName" type="xs:string"
                minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="oldclasses" type="Q1:OldClass" minOccurs="0"
                maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

The pom-definition is like this:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>json</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>xjc</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/jaxb</outputDirectory>
                    <packageName>getting.started.with.jaxb.generated</packageName>
                    <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/json</schemaDirectory>
                    <schemaFiles>newXSD.xsd</schemaFiles>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Any idea how to get this done is appreciated. I've got no clue any more how to proceed here. Is there a "Getting started" or other kind of documentation about this? I only found some discussions about specific problems but nothing very basic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with [episodic compilation](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Using-Episodes).

Comment: While this answer is correct, I suggest that you edit it to include more relevant information. Link-only answers are of limited value.

Comment: @Rob Given that he didn't even properly try to find an answer himself, the link is a good start. He still can refine his question to get help.

Comment: @Michael: thank you, the link is really quite a start. But I spent a lot of time to get familiar from scratch in knowledge about JAXB until this far. There is no good description about generating sources out there; at least not at codehaus or mojohaus where I had expected it. Even the site you mentioned is only a flash at the item; the configuration-parms are not described in detail and links to the samples often do not work,

Comment: I have never used the Mojohaus Plugin, I used the one from GitHub I have provided you. I have compiled several schemas with episodes with two levels of nesting so far. The Maven JAXB2 Plugin does a very a good job at that. What you should do is start with the plugin and show your results piece by piece.

Comment: We hava mojohaus running in our shop, so I started with this. But I tried with maven-jaxb-plugin as well, I get the logic so far; but cannot use it, at least not immediately. We currently create the "oldClasses" form the "oldXSD" to a path. A jar-file is created by a "install" later.

Comment: @Ulrich I cannot give any advise on the Codehaus Plugin. The other one does work. Maybe someone else can share his experience.